# You will never be slim(grammar)

Tags: grammar

> You will never **be** slim

Or

> You will never **become** slim

Or

> You will never **get** slim.

Which is correct?

Comment: Generally, you should study the differences between *to be* and *to become*. If unclear in some example, you should add some additional details to your question.

Comment: Which is correct? None are wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You will never **be** slim.

As the end result during some period of time, you will never be slim. The emphasis is on some point in time.

> You will never **become** slim.

*become* indicates a change of state, from not slim to slim. It would occur over some period of time.

> You will never **get** slim.

In your example, *get* has the same meaning as **become**.